# margin:auto doesn't seem to work, can't figure it out

Tags: html, css, center, margin

I'm trying to horizontally center the red "countdown" div, but it's not going my way. Have been stuck for hours but haven't yet found a single solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/737tM/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

  <div id="countdownWrapper">
    <div id="countdown">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
margin:0;
background:black;
overflow: hidden;}

#container {
height:100%;
width:100%;
z-index:-900;
position:fixed;
min-width:500px;}

#countdownWrapper {
width:100%;
height:100px;
bottom:0;
position:absolute;
display:block;}

#countdown {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
display:block;
width:400px;
height:100px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
position:absolute;
z-index:1000;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-top-right-radius: 20px;
background:red;}
```

Comment: Margins don't really play nicely with absolutely-positioned elements. Is there a reason you positioned it that way? I don't see any right, left, top, or bottom rules.

Comment: Yes, it was a reason until I put the #countdown inside the #countdownWrapper. Just forgot to remove position:absolute from the #countdown after assigning that value to the parent instead. Problem solved anyway, thanks for the fast feedback!

Comment: @user3716760 just a note, margins can be calculated in absolute positioned elements, but when you do it, the margins will be relative to the div left and top properties of the absolute positioned element. please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove your "position:absolute;" from countdown. Margins cannot be calculated on absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: -1, part of your answer fixes the problem, and then other part is just incorrect! margins can be calculated in absolute position elements, check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's fixed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uXLLp/)!

The problem was in the position absolute, **margins can be calculated in absolute positioned elements, but when you do it**, the margins are relative to the their position which is defined by left and top properties. Because you wanted it to be relative to the wrapper you needed to remove the absolute positioning from the countdown div. And that's it.

```
#countdown {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with you div is the

```
position:absolute;
```

property you have applied on the element named `countdown`.

Your center margining will work correctly if you just remove this property.

Also, contrary to the answer marked as the correct answer, margins DO apply on absolutely positioned elements. However, margins work differently on absolutely positioned elements as compared to statically positioned elements.

You need to learn how positioning works. Chris Coyier's article is certainly a good start -> http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you change the code to:

```
#countdown {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:block;
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    background:red;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

it will work. The reason is that in the normal content flow `margin: auto` equals '0' for the top and bottom, in your case `margin-left` and `margin-right` are 'auto' so their value equals '0'. `Position:absolute` breaks the block out of the typical content flow rendering the rest of the content as if that block wasn't there. Setting `top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;` gives the browser a new bounding box for the block.

Giving the block a width and height prevents the block from taking up all the available space and forces the browser to calculate `margin:auto` based on the new bounding box. Therefore: the margin of the absolute positioned element is then positioned inside these offsets. Since the block is absolutely positioned and therefore out of the normal flow the browser gives equal values to `margin-left` and `margin-right` centering the element in the bounds set earlier.

Hope this helps